# Core Data's raw date string

Tags: objective-c

Core data will store a date in a format like 441922215.
My sql query is grabbing those dates as strings.

Is there a way to get the raw date value of 441922215 back into a NSDate form?

Answer (score 1):

NSDate *date = [NSDate datewithtimeintervalsince1970:*coredata value*]